# Magento 2 passing Level 2 Data to Authorize.net

Tags: magento, magento2, authorize.net

In Magento 1.9.x, while using the core Authorize.net Direct Post payment method, "Additional Details - Level 2 Data" was sent from Magento to Authorize.net when an order was authorized and captured.

"Additional Details - Level 2 Data" includes Tax, Freight, Duty, and Tax Exempt.

We migrated to Magento 2.3.x using the core Authorize.net payment method - not Authorize.Net Direct Post (Deprecated) - and "Additional Details - Level 2 Data" is no longer being sent to Authorize.net. We are now on the latest version 2.3.2 and are still not seeing the "Additional Details - Level 2 Data" within Authorize.net.

Does anyone know how to setup Magento 2.3.2 to send "Additional Details - Level 2 Data" to Authorize.net?

Thank you in advance.